# Encountering Error when doing post-back using __doPostBack()

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, postback, dopostback

I am getting an error on javascript when doing post back. The code is as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function DoPostBack() 
{
    __doPostBack('Button2','My Argument');
}

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type="button" id="Button2" value="Press me" onclick="DoPostBack()" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Line: 13
Error: Object expected
```

I can't understand why this error is coming. Kindly help...

Comment: Kindly note I am using HTML button... not the asp.net button

Comment: @Danil is right, `_doPostback` is not some magic invisible function, it is created by ASP.NET when server controls are on a page which cause a postback. What are you trying to do here? Why can't you make is a serverside (asp.net) button?

Comment: @RPM1984 The current coding style cannot be changed in the application as it a ongoing one for the last 7 years and we have to follow it as of now, hence we can't use asp.net button.

Comment: Then you've have to do the "hack" that @mahmoud has suggested. or if you don't need a specific event handler, just use `document.forms[0].submit()` BTW - how did you handle this for the past 7 years then? Something seems fishy here.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a hidden button to do this task

```
Button1.Attributes.CssAttributes.Add("Display","None");
```

after hiding the button

you can call its click function from javascript

```
document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID%>').click();
```

this will call Button1_Click on server

** remember to set `UseSubmitBehaviour=false` to make this work on non-IE browsers

hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

__doPostBack is not created by default. If the page does not have a control that causes a postback then ASP.NET does not create/generate this method.
In your case you can force ASP.NET to generate __doPostBack by adding the following line in you Page_Load event:

```
ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);
```

This line will force the creation of this method.

Answer (score -1):

_doPostBack isn't created by default. It appears when you are adding control with autoPostBack=true or adding some grid with buttons in it.
So there is no _doPostBack javascript generated in your code.
If you add

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="list" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="first"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="second"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

for instance your code will work.
Don't know if it is really useful code :) however.