# Uncaught ReferenceError: __doPostBack is not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I am trying to execute a onserverclick but get the following error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: __doPostBack is not defined

This is my button

```
<input type="button" runat="server" style="padding:5px;" id="butSearch" onclick="if(!ManageCat())return;" onserverclick="butSearchCat_Click" value="Search" />

protected void butSearchCat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Why do I get this error and is there a fast way of overcoming this.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049670/encountering-error-when-doing-post-back-using-dopostback/20234444#20234444

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `__doPostBack('SearchCat','')` to your onclick

Try it as below:

```
 <input type="button" runat="server" style="padding:5px;"
 id="butSearch"
 onclick="if(!ManageCat())return;__doPostBack('SearchCat','')"
 onserverclick="butSearchCat_Click" value="Search" />
```

Comment: This should not have been the accepted answer. It's a poor and loose solution to hardcode such into your HTML.

Answer (score 2):

I see you were using Webforms. Put your `input` element inside a `<form runat="server">` tag and it should fix the not defined issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line of code in page load and try....

```
ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "");
```

Answer (score -1):

May be it will be better like tuhis: type="input"

Comment: that is not an answer, its more like a comment